# Unix Unable to mount share from Windows Nano Server

Tags: debian, windows-share, nano-server

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get any Debian install to mount any share I have on my Windows Nano Server install.  I can see them and access them from any Windows machine but Debian spits back the below error.

```
[83473.076686] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112
```

Here is what I've tried.

1) Started with...

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.15/TVShows /mnt/TVShows -o username=<DOMAINNAME>/unixshare_fid,password=<PASSWORD>
```

2) Added these parameters (in various combos)

```
ip=192.168.0.15
sec=ntlmv2
iocharset=utf8
```

3) Tried adding legacy server call Reg key to the Nano Server ([MS Document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/957441/client-connections-return-a-status-invalid-param-error-code-when-you-use-a-send-ntlmv2-response-only-authentication-level-in-windows-server-2008-or-in-windows-vista))

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\AllowLegacySrvCall
```

I know I'm no expert on this subject but I have to problems mounting shares from other systems, something is different with Nano, just not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have worked, not sure why though, maybe someone with more insight could chime in. But FINALLY this is working!

Banging my head against the wall I decided to install the Samba client and see if it gave me any more insight, well it started spitting out

```
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
```

This lead me over to this [POST](https://lists.samba.org/archive/linux-cifs-client/2015-June/006307.html) where it seems he was struggling with the same thing, it got me thinking and on the right path.  Long story short I had to do 2 things to get mounting to work.

1. Removed the  from the username flag
2. Added vers flag "vers=3.0"

Final product that seems to be working is..

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.15/TVShows /mnt/TVShows -o username=unixshare_fid,password=<PASSWORD>,vers=3.0
```